# FLEX App, Disabling the Back Button & Backspace/Delete Key from bumping out of the FLEX App

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash

Should disabling the back button, backspace/delete key be done in the FLEX App or in JavaScript?

Any suggested solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you should never take native browser control away from a user. While there are a few users that are going to inadvertently take themselves out of the app, the majority of users are going to be frustrated over not being able to perform an expected functionality (maybe not if you remove backspace, but definately if you take away the browser back button). Your overall frustration is going to be higher if you remove this functionality than if you leave it in default.

A better option is to open your app in a new tab or window. This takes away the need to remove any functionality and accomplishes your goal in a way that is acceptable to almost all users.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing it in JavaScript, but there are difficulties with either solution.  Different hardware platforms and browsers interpret keyboard signals differently, and I've had trouble capturing them with absolute certainty in Flash before.  Just Delete should be okay from either, though JavaScript might give you more flexibility to tweak this based on the user's browser/platform if you needed to.